# R Graphics: axis label placement relative to tick labels?

Tags: r, plot

I wanted to make a simple R plot with y-axis labels centered above the y-axis tick labels. I created something I liked with the code below. But it required some fumbling with the `at` graphical parameter.

Q: Is there a less hacky way of doing this? Is there a way to query the y-axis tick labels for their width so that I could use that information to center the y-axis label above them?

```
set.seed(1)
n.obs       <- 390
vol.min     <- .20/sqrt(252 * 390)
eps         <- rnorm(n = n.obs, sd = vol.min)
windows(width = 5.05, height = 3.8)
plot(eps,  main  =  "Hello  World!", las=1, ylab="")
mtext(text="eps", side=3, at=-60)
```

[image: my plot]

Comment: reasonable question. you can use `textwidth` to get the widths, I think, but you'd have to reconstruct precisely how R decided to format them. This is probably more cleanly achievable in grid graphics (but I don't know how)

Comment: As Ben Bolker said the above graph could easily be done in grid, but is that a route that interests you? Or do you intend to have more complex graphics where building such a custom plot function from scratch would make little sense?

Comment: @baptiste: You're right. I would like to be able to build more complicated graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the extent of the user coordinates with `par("usr") and then convert the units of margins. You have added an extra wringle by making the plot area non-standard. On a standard 7 x 7 device this works:

```
mtext(text="eps", side=3, at=usrcoord.x.left-0.075*diff(range(par("usr")[1:2]) ))
```

But on your smaller plot window, you need to use:

```
mtext(text="eps", side=3, at=usrcoord.x.left-0.1*diff(range(par("usr")[1:2]) ))
```

Comment: `usr` parameter is very helpful. I wasn't aware of and somehow overlooked it in the help. By `usrcoord.x.left` I assume you mean `par("usr")[1]`. After playing found I liked `mtext(text="eps", side=3, at=par("usr")[1]` which centered on the y-axis line instead.